# How to create a user that isn't bound my ip address in mysql?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

Currently I am creating a user for mysql (on ec2) like this:

```
grant all privileges on .... to ...@1.2.3.4 ..
```

The problem is, when my ec2 instance is stopped and restarted, it has a new ip address and I have to delete and create the user again.

Is there a way to not have to bind it to an ip address?  This user will be used on my web server to connect to another my database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe wildcard for domain is to `'user'@"%"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid getting a new ip on every reboot, why not just get an elastic ip that won't change?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Comment: Im using internal ip address, not external.